# Rails: Pycall can't import CountVectorizer from 'sklearn.feature_extraction.text'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pycall

I am having an issue (undefined method `module_eval`  when trying to import `CountVectorizer` from `sklearn.feature_extraction.text`.

My code:

```
pyfrom :'sklearn.feature_extraction.text', import: :CountVectorizer
```

[image]

Am I missing something, or is this library not supported yet on pycall?